# How to create nested directory with a specified permission bit for each of the parents directory created?

Tags: linux, permissions

The following isn't working as expected, and I am trying to understand if this is a bug or is there a hidden configuration in my linux machine that prevented it to create the folder with the correct permission. As a last resort, I could always fallback to creating the folder one by one, but I hope it doesn't come to this.

Here's what I do:

```
mkdir -m777 /familytree
mkdir -m755 -p /familytree/great-grandparent/grandparent/parent/myself/
```

This is what I got:

```
$ namei -m /root/grandparent/parent/myself/

dr-xr-xr-x /
drwxrwxrwx familytree
drwx------ great-grandparent
drwx------ grandparent
drwx------ parent
drwxr-xr-x myself
```

Here's what I expected:

```
   $ namei -m /root/grandparent/parent/myself/

dr-xr-xr-x /
drwxrwxrwx familytree
drwxr-xr-x great-grandparent
drwxr-xr-x grandparent
drwxr-xr-x parent
drwxr-xr-x myself
```

Comment: Based on the texinfo documentation (`info mkdir`), it looks like parent directories created by `-p` get their permissions from the `umask` even when `-m` is in effect (*Make any missing parent directories for each argument, setting their file permission bits to the umask modified by ‘u+wx’.*)